Interpretation and Validation of GLS Regression Results with High R² and Diagnostic Metrics
I'm studying the relationship between some economic variables, specifically YoY revenue growth of some industry (as the dependent variable), and some other economic indicators (as independent variables). Below are the cross-validation, OLS and GLS regression results obtained from my analysis, together with some plots of the residuals:

Best Model Selected
Performance Metrics:

MSE: 0.1681
RMSE: 0.3679
MAE: 0.2771
R² Score: 0.4572


Fitting OLS and GLS Models with the Best Feature Combination Using Statsmodels
OLS Regression Results



Variable
Coef
Std Err
t
P>|t|
[0.025 | 0.975]




Export_yoy__Differencing (Order 2)
0.2110
0.065
3.237
0.003
0.078 | 0.344


Sector_Employment_Index__Differencing (Order 2)
-0.1704
0.064
-2.681
0.012
-0.300 | -0.041


Revenue_lag_4__Yeo-Johnson Transformation
-0.3477
0.065
-5.323
0.000
-0.481 | -0.214


const
0.2522
0.063
3.987
0.000
0.123 | 0.381



Model Summary:

R-squared: 0.634
Adj. R-squared: 0.598
F-statistic: 17.88
Prob (F-statistic): 6.39e-07
AIC: 34.27
BIC: 40.49
Durbin-Watson: 2.132
Omnibus: 5.712 (Prob = 0.058)
Jarque-Bera (JB): 4.469 (Prob = 0.107)
Skew: 0.852
Kurtosis: 3.398
Cond. No.: 1.30


GLS Regression Results



Variable
Coef
Std Err
t
P>|t|
[0.025 | 0.975]




Export_yoy__Differencing (Order 2)
0.1747
0.028
6.179
0.000
0.117 | 0.232


Sector_Employment_Index__Differencing (Order 2)
-0.1868
0.024
-7.919
0.000
-0.235 | -0.139


Revenue_lag_4__Yeo-Johnson Transformation
-0.3377
0.015
-22.896
0.000
-0.368 | -0.308


const
0.2504
0.020
12.563
0.000
0.210 | 0.291



Model Summary:

R-squared: 0.981
Adj. R-squared: 0.979
F-statistic: 541.2
Prob (F-statistic): 7.60e-27
AIC: -13.76
BIC: -7.538
Durbin-Watson: 2.212
Omnibus: 23.670 (Prob = 0.000)
Jarque-Bera (JB): 3.836 (Prob = 0.147)
Skew: 0.283
Kurtosis: 1.480
Cond. No.: 33.2





Summary of Steps Taken

Data Loading and Preprocessing:

Extracted the dependent variable (Revenue__Original Series) and transformed independent variables for stationarity.


Feature Selection and Combination:

Split the features into groups, where each group comprised of the "base/original variable", its lagged versions, their stationarity-transformed versions.
For each group, scored features using Pearson correlation, and selected top k features (where k=2 or 3).
Generated feature combinations with up to three predictors.


Model Training and Evaluation:

Trained GLS models for each feature combination.
Evaluated models with MSE, RMSE, MAE, and R² metrics, using 4-fold cross-validation.
Selected the best model based on the lowest (average) RMSE.



Questions

High R² and Overfitting:

With an R² of 0.981 using only 35 observations and 3 predictors, could the model be overfitting? How can I verify this?


Specifying Covariance in GLS:

Are there best practices for specifying the covariance matrix in GLS to improve model performance?


Huge difference between OLS and GLS results:

Why is there such a large difference between the R² of the two models?




Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The last step is a problem: "Selected the best model based on the lowest RMSE." Such automated model selection that is very likely to overfit and not be reproducible in new data. You also started by pre-scoring predictors on individual Pearson correlations, another risk of overfitting. Grouping features should be done without reference to outcome values. See Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies, particularly Chapter 4. There might be other issues related to time series, but I'm not an expert on that topic.

@EdM thanks for the comment. I'm still reading up on the links you sent, but I've also modified the "Summary of Steps Taken" in my post as I actually also took some measures against overfitting, specifically grouping features that are similar and without reference to the target variable, and using cross-validation in model evaluation. Apart from my question about whether my approach to model selection is sound and how I can improve the estimation of the covariance matrix in GLS, I’m also wondering why there is a huge difference between the OLS and GLS results.

to Rsquared between OLS and GLS. Those Rsquared might be based on different definitions and so not be comparable between OLS and GLS, only comparable within the same class. The question does not provide information about which kind of GLS has been used. For example, AFAICS, Rsquared in statsmodels for WLS and GLS used the weighted or whitened sum of squares which will differ from the Rsquared for the original data. In the example, the parameter estimates of OLS and GLS are reasonably close, so we can expect that Rsquared defined on original data will also be close.
